# .htaccess/virtualhost dynamic blocklist + error document

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I currently have a multi-site virtual host, and I have set up some universal error documents that can be reset by each domain. I also have a blacklisting rewrite, but I'm trying to set a custom error condition if a IP is blocked, and then show a custom error page.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName catchall.host
    ServerAlias *
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/%0
    Alias /cloud-cgi /var/www/cloud-cgi
    SetEnv DIRECT_ACCESS no
    HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap access txt:/var/www/blacklist.txt
    RewriteCond ${access:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} deny [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ "/cloud-cgi/error_handler.php" [R=404,L]

    RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
    CustomLog /var/www/catchall_access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/catchall_error.log
</Virtualhost>
```

In `/var/www/` and `/var/www/hosts/` there is a htaccess setting the ErrorDocuments

```
ErrorDocument 400 /cloud-cgi/error_handler.php
ErrorDocument 401 /cloud-cgi/error_handler.php
ErrorDocument 403 /cloud-cgi/error_handler.php
ErrorDocument 404 /cloud-cgi/error_handler.php
ErrorDocument 500 /cloud-cgi/error_handler.php
```

In the vhost you can see the blacklist, where if the RewriteCond is met, tries to redirect the browser to `/cloud-cgi/error_handler.php` with HTTP code 404.

For some reason, when I try this, instead of getting to the custom ErrorDocument, I get the default Apache one. How can I trigger one of those HTTP errors, and redirect to the ErrorDocument. It would also be really nice if I could set a environment variable with a value so the handler can set a custom message. I've attempted to set the error document from the vhost definition as well, but without luck.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you are settings the `ErrorDocument` directive, consider setting it inside of the httpd.conf, which is what I usually do, it even works for 500 errors for me. And, please show me a screenshot of the default page once, so that I can get to know more about your problem.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ "/cloud-cgi/error_handler.php" [R=404,L]` is equivalent of `RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]`

Comment: @anubhava ohhhh.. I get it now. The rewrite rule is making it so that the errorhandler file is not existing. So, apache shows the default one.... hmm.. that must be the problem for the OP. Waiting for reply from the OP. I use PHP-FPM using proxy_fcgi, and that solves that issue for me by settings the status code in the errorhandler file. So this means that the OP does not want access to the actual errorhandler file. Which results in a simple problem.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ "/cloud-cgi/error_handler.php" [R=404,L]
> ```
>
> ...tries to redirect the browser to `/cloud-cgi/error_handler.php` with HTTP code 404

When you specify an HTTP status code with the `R` flag outside of the 3xx range then the *substitution* string is *ignored* (no substitution occurs). It is preferable to simply include a hyphen (`-`) as the substitution string in this case to explicitly show that a substitution is not intended.

When you specify `R=404`, Apache triggers a 404 response (via an *internal subrequest*) and will call the custom 404 `ErrorDocument` as defined.

However, the defined error document itself needs to be accessible. In the directives you posted, a request for `/cloud-cgi/error_handler.php` itself would also trigger a 404 response when the users IP address is on the blacklist, so the custom error document cannot be displayed. Apache falls back to the Apache default (and *complains* that either the custom error document triggered a 404 or even a 500 response, depending on where you are using these directives).

To make it accessible, you could either:

#### Include a specific exception

Include an exception in your rule, to exclude requests for the specific error document. For example:

```
 RewriteRule !^/cloud-cgi/error_handler.php - [R=404]
```

(The `L` flag is not required when specifying a non-3xx response code; it is implied.)

#### Include a generic exception

OR, more generically, prevent the rule being triggered when an error response has already been triggered. This can be achieved by examining the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is set to the HTTP response code after the error document is triggered. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

In the above we are simply checking that the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is empty. (*Aside:* This technique does not work on LiteSpeed servers, since the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is not updated during the request to the error state.)

#### Allow public access to the error document

But it's possible you have other directives that might also need to trigger an error document...

OR, use a mod_authz_core to permit public access. For example:

```
<Files error_handler.php>
Require all granted
</Files>
```

#### Prevent further rewrite processing when in an error state

OR, create an earlier exception and prevent further rewrite processing (in the current context) when `REDIRECT_STATUS` is set. However, this depends what other directives you have and now the order of the directives is important. For example, *before* your existing rule in the vHost config:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [END]
```

#### Internal rewrite

Alternatively, you internally rewrite the request to the custom error document. But you must now set the 404 response code in your PHP script (which ideally you need to do anyway in case the error document is requested directly - unlikely but not impossible):

```
RewriteRule ^ /cloud-cgi/error_handler.php [L]
```

> some universal error documents that can be reset by each domain

The problem here is that if they are reset by each domain then the specific exception included above will no longer be valid. You could have a specific subdirectory for all error documents and simply permit unrestricted access to that directory.

> It would also be really nice if I could set a environment variable with a value so the handler can set a custom message.

You can set an env var in the same `RewriteRule` directive. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYVAR:Message,R=404]
```

The above sets the env var `MYVAR` to the value `Message`. If your message text contains spaces then surround the entire flags argument in double-quotes. (Although I would leave your specific error text up to the `error_handler.php` and just set a short code or flag here.)

```
RewriteRule ^ - "[E=MYVAR:Custom message with spaces,R=404]"
```

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana Yeah, maybe TMI!? There are several different ways of doing essentially the same thing, but the preferred method could be dependent on the OPs config/requirements.

Comment: that's true. You are right. You might just be providing the single longest answer for the tag [Apache].  ... Generally, I use PHP-FPM with `ProxyErrorOverride on`, which makes it so that I can show a 404 error for every error (which I only do if the remote_addr is not local, for debugging purposes), by setting the status code, and this is the cool part of using php-fpm: It even sets the `REDIRECT_` environment variables, (I display them back to the user on the page) Which is just crazy. And, the user just cannot figure out where the error handler file is... 

Answer (score 1):

As [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) said... Try changing `RewriteRule ^ "/cloud-cgi/error_handler.php" [R=404,L]` to `RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]`

The rewrite rule is making it so that the errorhandler file doesn't appear to exist. So, because apache cannot access the errorhandler file, it shows the default one. And you should also be seeing a notice in the default error page, saying something like ***Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.***

Comment: Simply changing the `RewriteRule` in that way (replacing the _substitution_ string with a hyphen) won't actually make a difference. As anubhava states, it is "equivalent". In this instance (when stating `R=404`) the _substitution_ is completely ignored. But yes, the `RewriteRule` does effectively make the errorhandler file appear to not exist since the subrequest for the error document itself also triggers a 404 by the same rule. An exception needs to be created for the error document, as stated in my answer.